# deployment facing

Tags: sql-server

hi i am not able to create ssis catalog in my management studio?

it is  showing this error....

> ---
>
> The catalog backup file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\SSISDBBackup.bak' could not be accessed. Make sure the database file exists, and the SQL Server service account is able to access it. (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel)

Comment: is your sql service is running?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.  Trying to google my way through it.  Things I have noted in answers from other sites:

- Integration Services has to be part of your SQL Server install
  (update the product and add if missing, this will add the file)
- Version of SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Server engine need to match
- File may be in the wrong location, find it and copy it into where SQL Server is looking for it.
- Run SQL Server Management Studio as Administrator to avoid permissions issues

My solution was that I was attempting to create the SSIS DB on a remote server and not the server I was logged into.  Once I attempted on the local server it worked fine.

Comment: This might be better as a comment (although it is a passable answer).